# Recurrence: Theta of t(n) = 4t(n-1) -15

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations

First let me start off by saying that I am using the substitution method to solve this equation.Although any other methods will be welcomed, this is just the particular method I feel comfortable with.

I am getting to the end of the problem, but I have been unable to progress because I am stuck.

The problem is finding theta of

$$ t(n) = 4t(n-1) - 15 $$

Using the substitution method I was able to come up with...

$$ 4^2t(n-2)-2(15) $$

$$ 4^3t(n-3)-3(15) $$

$$ 4^k t(n+1-k)-k(15) $$

Then I tried to show this in summation form,

$$\sum_{i=n+1-k}^n i$$

I am fine with the problem up until the summation point, I am not sure what to do after summation in order to fully prove an answer.

Any help or guidance is appreciated it.

Comment: It might help to note that $$t(n)-5=4\cdot(t(n-1)-5).$$

Comment: Using what i think may be your method I seem to get $4^2t(n-2)-(1+4)(15)$ and then $4^3t(n-3)-(1+4+4^2)(15)$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I apologize, but I do not understand.

Comment: @Did I do not understand why you noted it like that. Do you mind explaining that?

Comment: Because I know how to solve the recursion $$s(n)=4\cdot s(n-1)$$ without much further ado. As you should. Do you?

Comment: @user352052: Maybe I don't know what you are doing when writing down the string of expressions. Are they all intended to be equal to $t(n)$?

Comment: What is $t(0)$?

Comment: @Did No, I don't honestly understand how to solve it. I understand the first bit you did now.  But these type of equations kill me. I don't care so much about the answer, I want to understand how to do the problem properly. I have been researching all morning and I haven't found anything particularly useful.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I was trying to show the equation as if it was going through a loop.

Comment: Then I think you should concentrate on fully solving the recursion $$s(n)=4\cdot s(n-1)$$ starting from, say, $s(0)=3$. Maybe compute a few terms and see what happens...

Comment: Maybe you are doing this, $t(n)=4t(n-1)-15=4(4t(n-2)-15)-15$. Then  you should get $4^2t(n-2)-(4)(15)-15$.  But I think the "unwinding" method is one of the more awkward ways of solving linear recurrences with constant coefficients.

Comment: Im confused, is solving theta of that just means you want to solve the recurrence?

Comment: @WillFisher Yes

Comment: @WillFisher: It can be done without solving the recurrence. But solving the recurrence is quite easy in this case. So one might as well do that first.

Comment: I would like to make an answer but I can't tell if solving the recurrence is all or if there is more that would like to be done.

Comment: @Did I see what you mean now.

Comment: @WillFisher I am just trying to solve the recurrence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, given that
$$t(n)=4t(n-1)-15;\qquad t(0)=t_0$$
We will, by inspection, guess that a solution might look like
$$t(n)=4^nt_0-15\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}4^k\qquad (1)$$
This can be proven using induction. Assume that $(1)$ holds for some $n$. Consider
$$t(n+1)=4t(n)-15$$
Using the inductive hypothesis we have
$$t(n+1)=4[4^nt_0-15\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}4^k]-15$$
$$=4^{n+1}t_0-15\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}4^{k+1}-15$$
$$=4^{n+1}t_0-15\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}4^n+1\right)=4^{n+1}t_0-15\sum_{k=0}^{n}4^k$$
Which is of the form $(1)$, thus it suffices to say that because $t(1)$ is of the form $(1)$, all $t(n)$ are of the form $(1)$. Now finally we are able to simplify $(1)$ using the [partial sum formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeometricSeries.html) for a geometric series and get
$$t(n)=4^nt_0-15\frac{1-4^n}{1-4}=4^nt_0+5(1-4^n)$$
$$=4^n(t_0-5)+5$$

**Note** I got a guess for what the answer would be by computing
$$t(1)=4t_0-15$$
$$t(2)=4^2t_0-4\cdot 15-15$$
$$t(3)=4^3t_0-4^215-4\cdot 15-15$$
And so on, and then looked at the patterns, similar to you but going up not down.

Comment: Ok, I finally got to 4^n thanks to help of Did. I did everything wrong, but seeing you go through the steps helps. I finally see what I missed and what I did wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

We know from theory that a nonhomogeneous linear recurrence will be in the form of a general solution plus a particular solution.

The general solution will come from solving the related homogeneous linear recurrence.

$h(n)=4(h(n-1))$

Looking at the characteristic polynomial $x-4=0$, we know this will then be of the form $h(n)=c_1 4^n$ for some constant $c_1$

The particular solution will be of a similar form as the nonhomogeneous part of the linear recurrence (with possible shifts due to possible overlap with general solution).  The nonhomogeneous part in this case is $-15$, so the expected particular solution will be a polynomial of degree zero, i.e. a constant.  Let this constant be called $p(n)=d_1$.  Plugging the particular solution into the recurrence will allow you to solve for the specific constants.

$p(n)=4(p(n-1))-15\Rightarrow d_1=4d_1-15\Rightarrow d_1=5$

Now that we have the particular solution, and knowing the general form of the homogeneous part, we know the closed form solution will look like the following:

$$t(n)=h(n)+p(n)=c_14^n + 5$$

Given initial conditions, one can now solve for $c_1$.  Let $t(0)=t_0$ be our initial condition.  Then we have:

$$t_0=t(0)=c_14^0+5$$, implying that $c_1=t_0-5$

The closed form solution is then:

$$t(n)=(t_0-5)4^n+5$$